# Get information from p12 certificate file using PHP

Tags: php, ssl, authentication, php-openssl, p12

My webpage has a login form that requests a p12 file to validate your identity using a certificate.

How can I get the p12 information using PHP code?

Comment: Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs12-read.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
$certs = array();
$pkcs12 = file_get_contents( "pkcs12file.pem" );
openssl_pkcs12_read( $pkcs12, $certs, "" );
print_r( $certs );
```

There are more in the documentation : [PHP.net doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs12-read.php)

Comment: he says .p12 file but you enter .pem file. is it usable for both?